# Odoo 8 - Compute Field with "store=True" can't store in database

Tags: field, store, odoo, openerp-8

I'm using `Odoo 8` and I have a problem with `compute field` with type is `Many2One`.

Here, I declared `department_id`:

```
department_id = fields.Text(
    string="Department", store=True,
    comodel_name="hr.department",
    compute="_get_department_id"
)
```

And fuction of this compute field:

```
@api.depends('employee_id')
def _get_department_id(self):
    if self.employee_id.department_id:
        self.department_id = self.employee_id.department_id.name
```

It seems to work right now, but it's not. In view, I can see the value of `department_id`. But in the database, the table has no column `department_id` and has no value of this column.

**My question is: how can I store the `department_id` in database?**

Notes:

- In the declaration of `department_id`, I set `store=True`, but it did NOT store the value of this field in database.
- I did a test. I add `compute_field` with type `Text`, It works, I don't know why compute field doesn't work with type `Many2One`.

  ```
  @api.depends('employee_id')
  def _get_compute_field(self):
  if self.employee_id.department_id:
      self.compute_field = self.employee_id.department_id.name

  compute_field = fields.Text(
      string="Compute Field", store=True,
      compute="_get_compute_field"
  )
  ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `store=True` works.
It may be that you added the computation to the field after it was created on the database. In this case the initial computation is not triggered.

A work around is to drop the column from the table and then upgrade your module. When the field is recreated the initial values should be computed.