# How to update compute fields which have store=True in Odoo8?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I have modified an existing field, `date_due`. I made it depend on `multi_date_due` (a one2many field I have created)', but it does not change when `multi_date_due` is modified. However, if I set store to False in `date_due`, the field is updated rightly.

I have tried to reinstall my module, to replace the original field in both python and xml code, but no way.

Python code:

```
class account_invoice(models.Model):

    _inherit = 'account.invoice'
    _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    date_due = fields.Date(
        string='Due date',
        readonly=False,
        compute=lambda self: self._compute_date_due(),
        store=True,
    )

    @api.multi
    @api.depends('multi_date_due.date_due')
    def _compute_date_due(self):
        for record in self:
            last_date = \
                datetime.strptime("9999-12-31 23:59:59", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            if record.multi_date_due:
                for multi_date_due in record.multi_date_due:
                    self._logger.warning(multi_date_due.date_due)
                    if datetime.strptime(\
                        multi_date_due.date_due, "%Y-%m-%d") < last_date:
                        first_date = multi_date_due.date_due
            else:   
                first_date = None
            record.date_due = first_date
```

XML code:

```
<record id="invoice_supplier_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">account.invoice.supplier.form</field>
    <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_supplier_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <data>
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='date_due']" position="replace">
                <field name="date_due"/>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='date_due']" position="after">
                <field name="multi_date_due" widget="one_to_many_list">
                    <tree string="Multiple due dates">
                        <field name="date_due" string="Due date"/>
                        <field name="invoice" invisible="1"/>
                    </tree>
                </field>
            </xpath>
        </data>
    </field>
</record>
```

This solution does not works for me:
[Odoo 8 - Compute Field with "store=True" can't store in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28834086/odoo-8-compute-field-with-store-true-cant-store-in-database)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The lambda in your field definition is possibly hiding the decorators. Try this:

```py
date_due = fields.Date(
    string='Due date',
    readonly=False,
    compute='_compute_date_due',
    store=True,
)
```

To force the recomputation for all records, drop the column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE account_invoice DROP COLUMN date_due;
```

Final recommendation for your code: use `fields.Datetime.from_string()` and `fields.Datetime.to_string()` rather than `strptime` / `strftime`: it makes the code easier to read.