# How do I update the value in related fields using onchange in odoo 10?

Tags: python-2.7, field, odoo, odoo-10

I am struggling now with how to update my fields because it is related to another field. In the time that I change the value of my related fields and save it, it goes back to its original value. Why? Can I update related fields? anyone help. I am new in odoo, many thanks.

here's what I do.

```
ret_condition_id = fields.Many2one('asset.state', string="Condition", 
    related='ret_asset_id.asset_condition', store=True)
```

If I change my ret_condition_id into a new value, after I save it. It goes back to its original value.

Comment: What is the original value is it `False` is you `Many2one` field have a value because related field save the changes but only of the Many2one field is set a value. but you cannot create a new record from related field. only with `delegate = True`.

Comment: I updated my post. Thanks. Anyways, what delegate exact means?

Comment: What is the value of `ret_asset_id`

Comment: ret_asset_id .asset_condition = 'new' and i want to change it to 'used'

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28834086/odoo-8-compute-field-with-store-true-cant-store-in-database, if `store=True` did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution on my question for the sake of others.
I have a button receive and everytime the state in on received the data will update.

```
return_ids = fields.One2many('asset.management.return.lines', 'ret_line_id', string="Asset")

@api.multi
    def button_received(self):
        self.state = 'received'

    for x in self.return_ids:
        holder = self.env['asset.asset'].search([('serial', '=', x.ret_serial_id)])
        for i in holder:
            i.write({'asset_condition': x.ret_condition_id.id})
            print 'pumasok return'
```

I created a for loop that will scan all serial on my asset.asset module that will equal on my data, then override the data on the field asset_condition equals to my current data

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Related field always based its value in a relationship, If you change the relation its value will recalculate, if you change the value of related field manually it will recalculate when you save the changes.

You should use another field for your purpose.

Comment: I already solve this problem, I use different methods. Anw thanks.

Comment: If my answer doesn't help you, please share with as your solution, it could help another person's